# How to click the ImageView in the firebaseRecyclerView?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I can get images and titles, texts in my post_row layout from my Firebase Server.

I want to click each items in the Recyclerview and I searched on them on google. but I couldn't find suitable codes implementing the click event in FirebaseRecyclerView.

and This is my FirebaseRecycler Adapter code!

thank you ~~!!

`mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("post");`

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    final Query DBquery = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("post").orderByChild("count");
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Post, PostViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Post, PostViewHolder>(
            Post.class,
            R.layout.post_row,
            PostViewHolder.class,
            DBquery
            mDatabase
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(PostViewHolder viewHolder, Post model, int position) {

            viewHolder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
            viewHolder.setDesc(model.getDesc());
            viewHolder.setImage(getApplicationContext(), model.getImage());
            viewHolder.setDate(model.getDate());
        }
    };
    mPostList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
}

public static class PostViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    View mView;

    public PostViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mView = itemView;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title){
        TextView post_title = mView.findViewById(R.id.post_title);
        post_title.setText(title);
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc){

        TextView post_desc = mView.findViewById(R.id.post_desc);
        post_desc.setText(desc);
    }

    public void setImage(Context ctx, String image){
        ImageView post_image = mView.findViewById(R.id.post_image);
        Picasso.get().load(image).into(post_image);
    }

    public void setDate(String date){

        TextView post_date = mView.findViewById(R.id.post_date);
        post_date.setText(date);
    }
}
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a listview to show your data, I use it like this and it's working really good.

Just inside `populateViewHolder`

```
                mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                        mDatabase = mAdapter.getRef(position);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UserEdit.class);
                        intent.putExtra("uid",mDatabase.getKey());
                        intent.putExtra("name", mAdapter.getItem(position).getNombre());
                        intent.putExtra("Email", mAdapter.getItem(position).getEmail());
                        intent.putExtra("paid", mAdapter.getItem(position).getPago());
                        intent.putExtra("connection", mAdapter.getItem(position).getUConexion());
                        intent.putExtra("connection2", mAdapter.getItem(position).getPConexion());
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
  mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

This is just an example from my code, it just clicks the list, get the item and pass it to another activity to work with that data.

With this you are setting the adapter data into a listview, and then clicking each item gives you the data of that position and you can manage that data in another activity if you need it.

The getters I'm using at the putExtras are being passed by the POJO class to the FirebaseList.

```
FirebaseListOptions<Usuarios> options = new FirebaseListOptions.Builder<Usuarios>()
                    .setQuery(query, Usuarios.class)
                    .setLayout(R.layout.item_row)
                    .build();
```

Here Usuarios is this:

```
  private String Nombre;
    private String Dispositivo;
    private String sexo;
    private String lenguaje;
    private String email;

    public Usuarios(){}

    public Usuarios(String nombre, String dispositivo, String sexo, String lenguaje, String email, String PConexion, String UConexion, String URL_frases, String URL_grupos, String URL_pictos, String edad, String pago) {
        Nombre = nombre;
        Dispositivo = dispositivo;
        this.sexo = sexo;
        this.lenguaje = lenguaje;
        this.email = email;
     ....
    }

    public  String getNombre() {
        return Nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        Nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getDispositivo() {
        return Dispositivo;
    }
....
```

Remember, here the variables nombre, email and so one need to be declared exactly as the Firebase database ones, otherwise you will see blank and results won't display, and remember in your `onStart` to place `mAdapter.startListening();`.

Comment: Thanks! and mAdapter. I don't have this variable in my code. so I didn't understand what it is??  could you explain it..?

Comment: mAdapter Is your firebase adapter in this case is firebaselistadapter

Comment: yes, Gastón Saillén. thank you. I solved it. but another issue is `intent.putExtra("name", mAdapter.getItem(position).getEmaill());` you can get an email by getEmail() methoid. but in my code, I can't call those getters.

Comment: nono, those getters are from the POJO class, i have a class that has setters and getters, this setters and getters should be exactly the same as the firebase database names, i will update

Answer (score 1):

To solve this, in your `PostViewHolder` class attach a click listener on your view like this:

```
mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        //Do what you need to do
    }
});
```

If you want to add a click listener on each view, then just find the views inside the `mView` object and attach the listener on each one of them. That's it!

Answer (score 1):

Add a function in your PostViewHolder say

```
public void init(int position){
itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override public void onClick(View view) {
                //Handle your click here
            }
        });
}
```

Now from populateViewHolder call

```
 viewHolder.init(position);
```

Answer (score 1):

Make ImageView Object outside the function as you did for mView .
And then in the populateViewHolder just add

```
viewHolder.imageView.setOnClickListener()
```

It'll work fine Guaranteed